# Google maps - is 3D view possible

Tags: ios, google-maps, 3d

I've seen this screen view.

[image]

Is it possible to get a 3D map in Google Maps SDK for iOS? I've seen normal, satellite, terrain, hybrid and none [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#change_the_map_type).

Answer (score -1):

Modifying the camera's viewing angle is supported by the SDK. Users can use a two-finger swipe gesture, or you can set `animateToViewingAngle:` on `GMSMapView`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/views?hl=de#introduction